# Can't install PackETH on Fedora 8

Tags: linux, fedora, ethernet

I want to install packETH on Fedora 8.

The command `sudo yum install packETH` doesn't work because no package is available.

I tried to download the source code and compile, but the following error appears:

```
gcc  -g -O2 -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0    -o packETH src/main.o src/support.o src/interface.o src/callbacks.o src/function.o src/function_send.o src/loadpacket.o src/savepacket.o  -lpthread -lm 
src/callbacks.o: In function `on_button92_clicked':
/home/hartes/packETH-1.7/src/callbacks.c:4807: undefined reference to `gtk_show_uri'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [packETH] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hartes/packETH-1.7'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@proj-119 packETH-1.7]#
```

I don't know how to solve this problem :`undefined reference to gtk_show_uri.`

Comment: What version of gtk? http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?p=7222

Comment: I solve the problem installing packETH-1.6 instead of packETH-1.7. Maybe because Fedora 8 is a bit oldfashion the new version of packETH aren't compatible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

taken from here: http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/Installation.html

**Compile problems:**

1) undefined error to :gtk_show_uri

This is due to some old versions of gtk on some distributions (*Centos 5.5 for example*). 
Open the `callbacks.c` file in the `src directory`, and inside the function `on_button92_clicked` **comment out or delete the line that starts with gtk_show_uri**...

But that means the donate button won’t work and this is bad luck for you, because you won’t be able to donate me!